# php can log but not echo inside foreach

Tags: php, foreach, echo

I have a foreach loop iterating over an array of objects. The goal is to output data to a table cell from each object in the array.   I go back and forth between HTML and PHP all the time, but this one won't output to the browser.   Inside the loop I can error_log the object, but I can follow directly with an echo statement OR closing PHP to write HTML, and neither of them gets printed.

The funny thing is that this is actually inside another foreach loop that is written exactly the same way and works fine!

Edit: OK, I've simplified the code as much as possible.  The error_log line writes "here" to the error log.   The next line does not echo "here" to the browser!

```
<div class='grid-x'>
    <?php
        foreach($form->awards as $award) {
            error_log('here');
            echo 'here';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

> RESULT:  Only the wrapping `<div class='grid-x'></div>` is printed to
>   browser.  Nothing inside, though the code is definitely iterating over
>   2 objects and console-logging "here" two times.

Things I've tried:

1. Getting rid of the wrapping `<div>`
2. Storing `$form->awards` in an array variable and iterating over that
3. Erasing and retyping the entire `<td>`
4. Copying the foreach line from other code where it works fine.
5. `echo` versus closing php `?>` and using HTML.
6. Removing the error_log line
7. For the sake of this post I removed the line checking if `$form->awards` exists.  I know it does in this instance.
8. Both echo('here') AND echo 'here';

Comment: According to the documentation [`echo`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) is not a function but a language construct which does not need opening and closing paranthesis. I would try to remove them for a start...

Comment: @MarkusSafar They do not hurt. They are treated as precedence operators.

Comment: You don't close foreach blocks with a semicolon. `<?php }; ?>` should be `<?php } ?>`

Comment: @Dharman, I agree but the documentation clearly state: *...does not behave like a function, so it cannot always be used in the context of a function.*

Comment: Also, does it work if you remove the `selog()` line completely?

Comment: @MarkusSafar It is not used in the context of the function here. What I am telling you is that these parentheses have a different meaning and they do not mean that echo is a function.

Comment: If you are really getting just `<div class='grid-x'></div>` then `$form->awards` is not an array/iterable. How are you console-logging it?

Comment: You need to show us the code for `selog`. My guess is that you have `exit/die` in there.

Comment: @Dharman I agree, I guess it was simply too late at my site ;-)

Comment: I do not usually use parenthesis with echo, but tried it here just as something to try.  It doesn't matter if I use the semicolon or not after the foreach, I get the same results.   I already noted that I tried removing the error_log line (selog), and I have used the selog function thousands of times, AND it DOES work here, which I've already noted.   It quite literally receives an object and error_logs the json_encoded object.

Comment: But the great thing here is that I'm realizing that I'm not the only one having trouble finding anything wrong here either.  At least it's not obvious, which makes me feel better!

Comment: Do you have error reporting switched on?

Answer (score 0):

I spend too many hours looking at code!

So I have 2 accordion tabs on the screen with a table inside of each.   I was looking inside the wrong accordion and therefore not seeing that the output WAS getting sent to the browser.

It's hard to believe I spent a couple hours on this, but I'm glad to know I'm not crazy and it was a simple answer.

Thank you to everyone who tried to help.

I will vote to delete this post.

Answer (score -3):

In fact, `echo` is not function, so you need to replace your line:

```
        echo ('here');
```

with

```
        echo 'here';
```

yes, if you want to use function to print something then you can use `print('Here')`

Comment: Tried this.  DIdn't make a difference.  I know, I can't figure it out. . . This answer also doesn't explain why the HTML does not print outside of the <?php ?> tags.